# How to make a currency restriction in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a question about XSD.

Suppose I have a currency like $500.00.

How can I set a restriction that the value should in range $0.00 - $1000.00

I can't use xsd:float directly because the dollar sign at the front.

How can I do? Any help are appreciated.

Comment: It would be best to have the number stored separately in another attribute or as simple content. For instance, you could have `<currency type="USD" value="1000" sign="$">`, <currency type="EUR" value="1000" sign="&#8364;">`. Then you can validate strings and numbers which is much easier.

Comment: If you need to deal with the **string** '$500.00' then you can use a regular expression restriction (see `<xs:pattern>`)

Answer (score 3):

If you treat the contents as a number (ex: `xs:decimal`) you can limit maximum and minimum values:

```
<xs:element name="money">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
            <xs:pattern value="\d*\.\d{2}"/>
            <xs:maxInclusive value="1000" />
            <xs:minInclusive value="0" />
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

But you can't have a `$` before the number, otherwise it's not a decimal. The pattern will force two digits after the decimal point. (You can also achieve this with `<xs:fractionDigits value="2"/>` but it will ignore extra zeros; ex: it will not restrict `123.0000`).

If you need to use the `$` then you have to treat the contents as a string. You can derive a new simple type using a regular expression to validate your string, but you won't be able to limit maximum and minimum values:

```
<xs:element name="money">
    <xs:simpleType>
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:pattern value="\$\d{1,4}\.\d{2}"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:element>
```

This will allow values between $0.00 and $9999.99 but it's not validating a number, but a string. That means it will also validate values such as $0001.00.

In case you decide to deal with numbers and strings separately, storing the number in one atrribute or simple content, and the string in another, then take a look at the answers to this question: [XML Schema How to Declare Price and Currency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8883514/xml-schema-how-to-declare-price-and-currency)

Comment: Also see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23246984/xsd-schema-with-restriction in case you decide to use pattern.

Answer (score 0):

First stuff, if you have to add the $ sign, the base value must be a string. here, an example,

```
 <xs:simpleType name="decimalType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
       <xs:pattern value="\$\d{1,4}\,*\d*" />
    </xs:restriction>
 </xs:simpleType>
```